# How would you translate "disposition (of the car)"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot

A business is conducting some preventive maintenance on its company cars. A form is used and lists checks performed. The form then has a section "disposition of the car" which lists choices such as "send the car for repair" and "put the car back in service" etc.

How would you translate "[disposition](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/disposition/576086) of the car"? This is about *[disposing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disposition) (of) it*, sort of like *dealing with* or some other meaning for which the translation is not readily available or clear.

Comment: I'd argue that even in english, the meaning of that title would not be obvious to everybody (but one would be helped by the options listed).

Comment: @jcaron Canadian English?

Answer (score 3):

Comme mentionné dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/53811/26366), dans ce genre de contexte j'ai vu « mesures à prendre ». J'ajouterais, similairement à une autre suggestion de cette réponse, [*destination*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9D2033) (du véhicule), « Emploi auquel une chose doit être affectée ; fonction qui lui est assignée » (Ac.9).

Answer (score 2):

I gather you mean "dispose of" as "get rid of" or "transfer". If so, indeed there's no straightforward translation of "disposition", in that case an option is to use a verb or a paraphrase in French. The first one that comes to mind is *se débarrasser de* but it won't do here since they are no getting rid of the car. Since the section offers different choices, I would suggest something like:

- *Que faire de la voiture ?* (What to do with the car?)
- *Étape(s) suivante(s)* (Next step(s))
- *Mesures à prendre* (Action to be taken)
- *Affectation du véhicule/de la voiture*

I much prefer the last two choices. You might want to add something like *selon l'état de la voiture* (*Affectation selon l'état de la voiture*), but it might be too long for a section title, and I expect this is implied from the context.

Comment: Pourrait-on utiliser aussi _suites_? _Suites à porter_?

Comment: @Frank Porter des suites? Bof...  on **apporte** plutôt des suites (sauf s'il s'agit de suites judiciaires), mais donner est me semble-t-il plus fréquent. Mais je préfère de loin Mesures à prendre que suites à donner...

Comment: On pourrait aussi essayer _suites à envisager_. Je ne sais pas si c'est très courant, mais ça se comprend très bien. En fait, ça se dit effectivement: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suites+%C3%A0+envisager&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3

Answer (score 2):

Deux autres possibilités pourraient être:

- *suites à envisager*
- *suites à apporter*

Les ngrams google semblent supporter ces deux possibilités:

[image]

Comment: ou "action envisagée".

Comment: I'd favor "Suite à donner" over "Mesures à prendre". Also, consider "Dispositions ultérieures" (plural) and the simple "Décision".